# Python Code for downloading data as csv from Mysql is not working

Tags: python, mysql, csv, export-to-csv

I have some code to get data from Mysql and download as csv. 
Not able to understand why I get this error:

```
error:    csv_writer.writerows([cursor])
_csv.Error: sequence expected
```

My Code :

```
import time
import ConfigParser
import sys
import wget
import pymysql.cursors
import pymysql
import re
import csv

configParser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
configFilePath = r'../credentials.cfg'
configParser.read(configFilePath)

User = configParser.get('your-config', 'user')
Pswd = configParser.get('your-config','pswd')
Host = configParser.get('your-config','hostdps')
db = pymysql.connect(host=Host, user=User, password=Pswd, db='Apis2', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,local_infile=True)


cursor = db.cursor()
SELECT_TABLE = """select * from """+DB_NAME+"."+STATES_INPUT_TBL
cursor.execute(SELECT_TABLE)

with open("out.csv", "wb") as csv_file:              # Python 2 version
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
  if cursor:
      csv_writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cursor.description]) # write headers
      csv_writer.writerows([cursor])
print open('out.csv').read()
```

Comment: I suspect that `csv.writer` knows nothing about `db.cursor`. You may have to iterate through the cursor your self, calling `writerow` for each database row.

Comment: data = cursor.fetchall () gives :   "{u'metro_name': u'Phoenix-Mesa-Glendale, AZ', u'cb_ps': 38060}" 
For each row and printing the column index name before each value. Any ways to remove this?